# Canvas Particles - Update canvas size on Window Resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, canvas

I'm very new to Canvas animations, and I'm stuck on something and wondering if you guys could help me out.

I'm using this demo - http://cssdeck.com/labs/html5-canvas-particles-web-matrix - but I need it to recalculate the canvas size when the window is resized. This needs to be updated in the jQuery, not the CSS or HTML (FYI, CSS is canvas width & height = 100%).

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Have you tried to resolve this on your own yet? Can you show what you tried?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Here, we deal with questions about coding problems rather than (your) design problem. Here's a starting plan for you to code with:  (1) Clear the canvas, (2) scale the entire canvas with `context.scale(scaleFactor,scaleFactor)` (*Note: you must scale proportionally or the drawings will appear distorted*) & (3) redraw the particles. Come back to Stackoverflow if you have problems with the code you write. :-)

Comment: Thanks guys. Neal - I tried this:

`window.onresize = function() {
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

// Initialize the context of the canvas
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Set the canvas width and height to occupy full window
var W = window.innerWidth, H = window.innerHeight;
canvas.width = W;
canvas.height = H;

// Some variables for later use
var particleCount = 150,
 particles = [],
 minDist = 70,
 dist;
}`

Basically duplicating the initialization code and firing it again on window resize - but it doesn't work... (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) - It redraws the canvas which is good (it stops stretching the particles) but it doesn't update the dimensions, so the particles only exist within the boundaries of the pre-resize canvas size. (Hope that makes sense!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your event `window.onresize` should not declare new variables `H` and `W` but use 'old' ones instead, like this:

```
window.onresize = function() {  
   W = window.innerWidth;
   H = window.innerHeight;
   canvas.width = W;
   canvas.height = H; 
}
```

If you want to modify other parameters like `particleCount`  or `particles` array also don't use `var`, because it will create new variables in function scope.